# Can I use my pc as a proxy for connected smartphone?

Tags: networking, proxy, android

EMR might not be good for us. I know I can use my smartphone as a router for my PC, but I wondered if I could do the reverse? I.E. connect my smartphone to my PC via USB and get to the internet via my PCs inernet?

Why, you ask? Well, I've turned off Wi-fi and mobile data, but would like to get the updates for the phone.

I've got an Android phone and the PC has Ubuntu 14.04

I want to do all this using wires to minimise brain-frying.

Thanks

mini

Comment: No you can't get your internet through the PC in this way. Perhaps someone has developed some third party app for this but I have never seen one.

Comment: it does work, see here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can, if your phone supports NDIS or something like that - i.e. it can do ethernet-over-usb with your PC. Android and Ubuntu on both points are pretty capable of it as a software layers, so the only question is the hardware capabilities. Try investigating your device list in android console - it will show you where to dig.

Answer (score 0):

It's called Internet pass through or reverse tethering. If your phone is rooted, there are a few apps in the market you can use to do this.

Here's one that worked on my HTC m7 running CM11: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jasongong.tether.usb

What's your phone's make, model, and ROM?